# css show if screen size 1200 or more or between

Tags: css

Hello I want to show a different logo depending the size of the page viewed on a mobile divice.

I want to show an image if the page width is greater than 1025px or more,  show another image if the screen size is between 600 and 1025px, or show an another image if the screen size is max 300px. I only ever want to show one image. No matter what I try I show either all three or only one. Can anyone enlighten me. thank you

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 1025px) {
#logo768 { display: none;}
#logo1025 { display: none;}
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
#logo1025 { display: none;}
#logo300 { display: none;}
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 399px) {
#logo768 { display: none;} 
#logo1025 { display: none;}
}
```

Comment: You need to think about what `max-width` and `min-width` actually mean in relation to your natural language description of the problem. You state, "if the screen size is max 300px", yet in your media query you've stated `min-width: 399px` (why not `max-width`?).  In short, you seem to have your logic back to front. Also consider the order of these directives.

Comment: So the usual approach is: `max-width` if you want to apply styles **up to** that width; `min-width` if you want to apply styles **from** that width onwards; so if you want a range for example you could say: `@media (min-width: 300px) and (max-width: 600px)` so those styles only apply from 300px onwards but up until 600px

Comment: what you want to show when scren width is between 300 and 600?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider using `picture`. It's a more elegant approach and easier to maintain. The `<img>` here is the default image that is used when the viewport is smaller than `400px`.

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/picture):

> The HTML `<picture>` element contains zero or more `<source>` elements and
>   one `<img>` element to provide versions of an image for different
>   display/device scenarios. The browser will consider each child
>   `<source>` element and choose the best match among them; if no matches
>   are found, the URL of the `<img>` element's `src` attribute is selected.
>   The selected image is then presented in the space occupied by the
>   `<img>` element.

```css
img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<picture>
  <source 
    media="(min-width: 1024px)"
    srcset="https://placekitten.com/1024/400">
  <source 
    media="(min-width: 768px)"
    srcset="https://placekitten.com/768/300">
  <source 
    media="(min-width: 400px)"
    srcset="https://placekitten.com/400/200">
  <img src="https://placekitten.com/300/200" alt="one or more kittens" />
</picture>
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/antibland/9pjnohbu/12/)

Comment: thank you, but i need to hide an entire div as its for the headder where the nav is plus logo. I need to change all per page size'ish. thanks for your help